# Get all contacts phone number from address book got crash?

Tags: ios

I've done below code to try getting all contacts phone number from address book:

```
  ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
  NSArray *arrayOfPeople = 
  (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);    
  NSUInteger index = 0;
  allContactsPhoneNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  for(index = 0; index<=([arrayOfPeople count]-1); index++){

    ABRecordRef currentPerson = 
    (__bridge ABRecordRef)[arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex:index];

    NSArray *phones = 
    (__bridge NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(
    ABRecordCopyValue(currentPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty));

    // Make sure that the selected contact has one phone at least filled in.
    if ([phones count] > 0) {
      // We'll use the first phone number only here.
      // In a real app, it's up to you to play around with the returned values and pick the necessary value.
      [allContactsPhoneNumber addObject:[phones objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    else{
      [allContactsPhoneNumber addObject:@"No phone number was set."];
    }
  }
```

However, it works well in iOS 6 but not in iOS 5.
It got crash on following code:

```
ABRecordRef currentPerson = 
(__bridge ABRecordRef)[arrayOfPeople objectAtIndex:index];
```

The output prints:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'
```

Anyone has advice why it got crash? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an issue depending on iOS5/iOS6 but an issue with different testing environment. In once case (one simulator, I guess) you have contacts in your addressbook, in the other you don't.

But your test in your `for` loop will fail for the case when `[arrayOfPeople count]` is zero, because `count` returns an `NSUInteger`, which is **unsigned**, and subtracting `-1` to `0UL` creates an underflow (as `-1` interpreted as an unsigned integer gives you the maximum value of an integer instead, because `-1` is negative and unsigned integers can only store positive integers of course).

So when you don't have any contact and `[arrayOfPeople count]` is zero, you are entering into your `for` loop anyway thus the crash when trying to get the object at index 0 in your empty array of people.

---

Replace your condition in your `for` loop from

```
for(index = 0; index<=([arrayOfPeople count]-1); index++)
```

To

```
for(index = 0; index<[arrayOfPeople count]; index++)
```

And  your crash should go away as you won't underflow and won't enter in your `for` loop when you don't have any contact in your addressbook.

Comment: thanks a lot, you save my life :') this is a very trivial issue